# Can .NET provided APIs get obfuscated too?

Tags: .net, obfuscation

I am considering using obfuscation for my .NET application. My question is that any of these obfuscators also obfuscates any .NET APIs that my code calls. So for example if my class calls any .NET file stream functions or socket related APIs, will they also get obfuscated?

Comment: Ask yourself how that would even work and you'll know the answer to this question.

Comment: @siride, why should not it work? You won't be able to do anything with P/Invokes, but all of the managed code can be obfuscated. But, unfortunately, a license won't let you do it.

Comment: @SK-logic: because the public .NET APIs still are what they are and at some point, they will have to be called using the normal means, which are visible to decompilers.  Even logicnp's obfuscator just adds a small layer between the app and the public calls.  You can't make them go away.

Comment: @siride, it is true for intrinsics and P/Invokes. But the managed parts of mscorlib and alike can be (theoretically) obfuscated (or optimised, or whatever else), and the only thing that does not allow doing it is the license. Of course a result of this obfuscation will be tied to a very specific version of the .NET runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to obfuscate the **calls** to .Net APIs, [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) does exactly this - it replaces method calls made to .Net APIs with proxy methods.

Before:

Application.EnableVisualStyles();

After:

A.A();

DISCLAIMER: I work at LogicNP Software, the developer of Crypto Obfuscator.

Comment: Can you confirm that the application will still be functional after I do this? Because some folks here seem to claim that application will not be functional if .NET API calls are obfuscated.

Comment: Yes, it will work. "Method call Obfuscation" (mentioned by Roger Smith below) is what Crypto Obfuscator does.

Answer (score 0):

Public names of classes, properties, parameters, fields and methods will not be obfuscated.

The API you expose to referencing assemblies must be public, so, the API will not be obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

No, the system .NET assemblies — quite naturally — won't be obfuscated. They aren't your code. Unless you *try* to include them among your obfuscation configuration they won't be touched. In case you *do* include them, you most likely will end up with a non-functioning result.

Also, people usually don't obfuscate `public` APIs (classes, members, …). However, in case they are public for the sake of binding within your software *only*, your obfuscator might be capable of obfuscating them as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible in theory to obfuscate your calls to the .net libraries, but not the .net libraries themselves obviously.

One could replace the calls to library functions with delegate calls in many places. That'd result in a certain performance hit, and some things like ngen might be affected. And it only protects against simple reflection of your assemblies, and not when your code runs in a debugger.

Comment: @SKLogic You can obfuscate your own libraries, but I don't understand how you want to obfuscate the .net framework libraries. You probably can't even include obfuscated versions of them in your own program because you probably don't have a license for that. Perhaps if you use mono you can do something like that.

Comment: yes, license does not allow including modified parts of a framework into your own deliverables. But you can do that with Mono.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually it is called cross assembly obfuscation. It is really  needed for perfect obfuscation.

Renaming of external references thus dramatically increasing the number of obfuscated constructs. Given a set of assemblies that interface each other, FxProtect will rename classes, methods and fields referenced from other assemblies uniformly. For example, if class A declared in assembly A is referenced from assembly B and FxProtect renames class A to A1, it will also rename B's external reference from A to A1.

I am using cross assembly obfuscation with FxProtect. You can try it... **[.NET Obfuscator](http://www.maycoms.net)**